# Webrtc - How to add Video MediaConstraint in android?

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android, videocall

In webrtc, how to add video constraints such as min_height, max_height, min_fps etc., in Android using the peer connection?

Answer (score 0):

> You can add it using MediaConstraints KeyValuePair

```
 videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxHeight", Integer.toString(videoHeight)));
 videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxWidth", Integer.toString(videoWidth)));
 videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxFrameRate", Integer.toString(videoFps)));
 videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("minFrameRate", Integer.toString(videoFps)))
```